# Output from .activeInHierarchy still true when object is being disabled Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently learning the basics of Unity and, *as always when one is learning something new*, I'm a bit stuck.

There is a falling cube that is being set inactive when it collides with something. I was planning on making a parent script that checks if the cube is active or inactive. And when it's inactive, it outputs the state of the boolean `eActive` in the console.

But whenever the falling cube is colliding with something it does disappear, but the output of the boolean is still true.

Both scripts:

Enemy.cs

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {

GameObject enemy;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    enemy = GameObject.Find("Enemy");
    enemy.SetActive(true);
}

public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    enemy.SetActive(false);
}
}
```

EnemySpawn.cs

```
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySpawn : MonoBehaviour {

GameObject enemy;
public bool eActive ;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    enemy = GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy");
    eActive = enemy.activeInHierarchy;
    Debug.Log(eActive);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    Destroyed();
}

void Destroyed()
{
    if (!eActive)
    {
        Debug.Log(eActive);
    }
}
}
```

Would love to hear what I'm doing wrong and if there are better ways to do these kind of things in Unity!

Big thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code

1-) You assign a value to `eActive` in `Start` and never update it when object is disabled. So it is always true because it is never updated.

2-) Use `GameObject.activeSelf` instead of `activeInHierarchy` since you just enable and disable the object and your object has no **parents!**. Also you do not need a boolean variable to hold `activeSelf` or care about updating it. Unity does this for you just use it.

So your `Destroy` method should look like this:

```
void Destroyed()
{
    if (!enemy.activeSelf)
    {
        Debug.Log("Enemy is not active");
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: It is now outputting the right thing! Thanks alot :)